# ErrorException (E_ERROR) :Trying to get property of non-object. when i trying implode array to string in index.blade.php

Tags: laravel

index.blade.php

```
@php
    $p = [];
    foreach($p->genres as $genre){
        $genres[] = $genre->genres;
    }
    $genre = implode(",", $genres);

@endphp
<span>{{$genre}}</span>
```

Controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $series = Series::all();

        return view('admin/series/index',['series' => $series]);


    }
```

model Genres.php

```
class Genres extends Model
{       
    protected $primarykey=  'id';
    protected $fillable = ['genres'];

    public function series()
     {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Series::class);
   }
}
```

Model Series.php

```
class Series extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'series';
    protected $primarykey='id';
    protected $fillable = ['title','country','japanese','year','synonyms','trailer','image','network','rating','duration','genres','aired','directors','screenwriters','score','type','episode','synopsis'];

    public function genres(){
    return  $this->belongsToMany(Genres::class);
    }
}
```

I want to display data from different databases using multiple table relationships, but the data is still a compilation array to bring it up.
and compilation I asked a friend. I was told to use a code like the one in `index.blade.php`. and return like this

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Try to get properties that are not objects

Comment: In the first line $p = [], it's an empty array and you are accessing $p->genres from an empty array. So only it says trying to get a property of non-object error.

Comment: how do I request an array of data from a database? the data in the database is not in the form of an array, but in the form of ordinary data. but when called it changes to an array.
I use the relation of many tables on many

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing array with *->* whereas only the object can be accessed with arrow. To access array keys you have to use *$array['key']* approach.

Arrays and objects are two different data types, so to access their inner data, you've to use their respective approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping wrong variables/collections. You need to make some changes to make it work. Below code should solve your problem.

```
@php
$p = [];
foreach($series as $ser){
    foreach($ser->genres as $genre){
        $p[] = $genre->genres;
    }
}
$gen = implode(",", $p);
@endphp
<span>{{$gen}}</span>
```

Comment: I get an error like this Invalid argument supplied for foreach ()

Comment: please be specific. which line you are getting this error? You should add some sample data from database to test

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `series` from the controller so inside the view you must loop over the series first.

```
@foreach($series as $s){

    // then your code should be take place.

    @php
        $genres = [];
        foreach($s->genres as $genre){
            $genres[] = $genre->genres;
        }
        $genre = implode(",", $genres);

    @endphp
    <span>{{$genre}}</span>

@endforeach
```

Comment: @Sultan Achmad let me know if it helps